# Jenkins error in build Invalid parameter "bucket", did you mean "entries"?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

Hi I am running jenkins on my local.I installed the S3 publisher plugin, and restarted jenkins

If nothing else does anyome know what the error Invalid parameter "bucket", did you mean "entries" is it a jenkins error saying it does not recognize the word Bucket. In which case it may mean my S3 publisher plugin is not working

WorkflowScript: 32: Invalid parameter "bucket", did you mean "entries"? @ line 32, column 26.
s3Upload(bucket:"${APP_CONFIG_BUCKET}", file:"${TARGET}",  path:"${BUCKET_PATH}")
^

Thanks for any help

Comment: The `s3Upload` method of the S3 publisher plugin has no parameter called  `bucket`, see the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/s3/). Instead you are probably trying to use the [s3Upload](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/#s3upload-copy-file-to-s3) step of the [AWS Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/) plugin which has exactly those parameters, and is an entirely different plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are correct, I insatlled AWS Steps and it worked.